AppStore Asset validation failed 90270 and 90259 MAUI App
Our Blazor MAUI Hybrid app is in production and the other week it was working fine to upload a new version to App Store with Transporter. However, when trying this now it gives us the errors:
Asset validation failed (90270)
Unsupported toolchain. Packages submitted to the App Store must be created either through Xcode, or using the productbuild[1] tool, as described in "Submitting your Mac apps to the App Store." Packages created by other tools, including PackageMaker, are not acceptable. [SIS] (ID:...)

Asset validation failed (90259)
Bad Bundle Executable. You must include a valid CFBundleExecutable key in your bundle's information property list file. (ID: ...)

We are compiling with XCode 15.4 on macOS 14 Azure DevOps Hosted Agent. We also tried using RootNamespace as value to CFBundleExecutable by doing below in info.plist but still get the error above.
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>Company.My.App</string>

Any suggestions on how to resolve these issues? We are stuck on how to resolve this.

There are new rules in Apple have a look here @Gerald Versluis | https://youtu.be/D7R87wm9IJE?si=YxfaKsvrzfdke7m9

As far as I know, the two error messages typically appear when there are issues with the assets included in the app package. This can include improperly formatted assets, missing assets, or assets that do not meet the App Store's requirements. you can try to check these things.

In addition, did you try on your local macOS 14 with XCode 15.4 to build and upload the new package version to App Store with Transporter? Does the issue exist on local?

Thanks for the reply @BrightRan-MSFT . We do not have a proper local setup to compile the app so not sure if local compilation works. The thing is that we did not change anything in the app artifacts so pretty sure it isn't an issue with the assets but rather something with the new rules that we are missing, watched some of that video but did not really get any answers from that what I should do.

@Smith5727, You mentioned the pipeline could work before. Did you also use the agent macOS 14 with XCode 15?

@Smith5727, If the issue is related to the new rules  of Apple, I am afraid that you need to get a local macOS machine to adjust the configurations and settings of your app to make it can work with the new rule on local at first. If it cannot work on local, it is not possible to guarantee it can work in pipeline.

I think this has to do with the new requirements and it should be possible to fix it somehow but not sure how. We've tried both macOS 13 and 14 and XCode 15.1 and XCode 15.4 and same issue now. A week ago or so macOS 13 with XCode 15.1 worked fine. Maybe MAUI devs know more about this?

@Smith5727, Yes, looks like the problem is not laying on Azure DevOps pipelines. It should be with the new Apple rules or some other updates from Apple as mentioned previously.
